# Aligning Time inside a Text Speech Bubble

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, whatsapp

I want to implement this feature, as present in WhatsApp in ***Android***.

[image: 2 speech bubbles]

Here, for implementing this I used separate **TextViews** for both **text** and **time**, placed inside a relative layout.

My Question is, how WhatsApp is deciding when to move the time in the new-line and when not.

Below are the Portrait and Landscape screenshot of WhatsApp.

[image: Portrait View]

[image: Landscape View]

Instinct feeling is, code must be something like this.

```
if(width_of_last_line_of_textview > some_fixed_value)
    move time_textview to new-line;
else
    make time_textview in-line;
```

But I was wondering if this can be done using xml (using some property weight etc)

WhatsApp bubble adjusts itself on every screen size, whether the screen is Landscape or Portrait.

---

*Attached is the layout WhatsApp using for text bubble.*

**conversation_row_text_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<com.whatsapp.DividerView
    android:id="@id/date_divider"
    style="@style/DateDivider" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/date_divider"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40.0dip"
    android:minHeight="30.0dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/web_page_preview_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="8.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="8.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="8.0dip" />

    <view
        android:id="@id/text_content_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.whatsapp.TextAndDateLayout"
        android:paddingBottom="2.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="2.0dip" >

        <com.whatsapp.TextEmojiLabel
            android:id="@id/message_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="3.0dip"
            android:paddingLeft="8.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="8.0dip"
            android:paddingTop="2.0dip"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/conversation_text_row_tv" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/date_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
            android:paddingRight="5.0dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/date"
                style="@style/ConversationDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|right"
                android:gravity="right" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center|right"
                android:paddingBottom="3.0dip"
                android:paddingLeft="4.0dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </view>
</LinearLayout>
```

WhatsApp is using **LinearLayout** for Date, it contains TextView (for date i.e **3:48 PM**) and ImageView (for icons i.e **✔**)

Comment: It seems it's using a FlowLayout...

Comment: @BobMalooga i have added the WhatsApp layout code, it seems like they are doing this from Java not from xml, may be.

Comment: `it contains TextView (for date i.e 3:48 PM) and ImageView (for icons i.e ✔)` Then WhatsApp is **not optimized**. They should use a **compound drawable** directly inside the TextView, for the ✔ icons.

Comment: whatsapp uses custom view defined in `com.whatsapp.TextAndDateLayout` class.

Comment: @shanraisshan did you find any solution?

Comment: @Syeda Zunairah try [Flexbox Layout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html?m=1)

Comment: But it didn't make the both text views to overlap for example when we have a text of 1.5 lines we want the time to be below the first line and on the front of the second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android open sourced [FlexboxLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html) to bring the same   functionalities of the CSS Flexible Layout module to Android.

[image: FlexBoxLayout]

Answer (score 3):

As @Bob Malonga mentioned on your comment my opinion is also this layout can be achieved by using FlowLayout.

> FlowLayout let us adding views one to another until total width of views reached maximum width. Then it will continue from new line.

You can find example FlowLayout libraries below

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

In your case , main point will be you need to set `android:gravity` value as `right` , by this way when your **time_text_view** exceed the width, it will be on new line and it will be aligned to **right**

Comment: WhatsApp aren't using Flow Layout.

Comment: I dont know what layouts whatsapp are using , but your need can be achieved with flowlayout